# Dataframe to_excel method does not create workbook with dataframe contents

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm using python 3.8 and created a simple script to extract issues from JIRA, aiming to export to Excel via a dataframe. I can print the dataframe contents on the Terminal perfectly, but when trying to export the dataframe to Excel it does not get generated, although I don't receive any errors! Below an excerpt of my python source code. (Pandas version = 1.1.4) Many thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
from jira.client import JIRA
.....
.....
jiraissues = jc.search_issues(query1, 0, block_size)

print(len(jiraissues)) # of issues found (I get 45 for the particular query)

issuesdf = pd.DataFrame()

for issue in jiraissues:

    #add jira data to dictionary
    d= {
        'key': issue.key,
        'type': issue.fields.issuetype,
        'created': issue.fields.created,
        'updated': issue.fields.updated,
        'summary': issue.fields.summary,
        'status': issue.fields.status    
        }

    issuesdf=issuesdf.append(d,ignore_index=True)


print(issuesdf)  #--this prints DataFrame contents correctly (52 rows x 15 columns)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('JiraExport.xlsx')

issuesdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')  #Excel workbook 'JiraExport.xlsx' is not generated and hence not listed in the file explorer anywhere

writer.save
```

Comment: Does it work if you do it without the writer? e.g. `issuesdf.to_excel('JiraExport.xlsx')` And does `.to_csv()` or other writers work?

Comment: doesn't look like you are defining the writer correctly. https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_simple.html

Comment: That worked @kfinity! I spent many hours figuring out the root cause so many thanks for your swift response!